# PHP foreach loop, how to use variables retrieved in another function between iterations?

Tags: php, xml, json, variables, foreach

I'm new to PHP and I'm learning some dynamic data retrieval from xml and json files. I have made two codes to do two separate things. The first one is an xml games list data as seen here:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/id/aksn1p3r/games?tab=all&xml=1
```

What I would like to do is combine two ways of getting data, from that xml and then, using the variable $appid to get a bit more info from another json data source, before it iterates the next $gdata.

```
<?php

$glist = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/aksn1p3r/games?tab=all&xml=1';
$gxml = simplexml_load_file($glist);

foreach($gxml->games->game as $game) {

$appid = $game->appID;
$glink = $game->storeLink;
$gname = $game->name;
$glogo = $game->logo;

echo '<p>'. $appid . ' <a href="'. $glink .'">'. $gname .'<br>';
echo '<img src="'. $glogo .'" /></a></p>';

}

?>
```

Here is a **json**: [http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=8870] that is constructed by using the variable named **$appid**.

I want it to contruct a new link before the next iteration in the loop above, and then get the **price aka $gprice** from the json source, as below:

```
<?php

$appid = '8870';

$ht = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=' . $appid;

$fgc = file_get_contents($ht);
$jd = json_decode($fgc, true);

$gdata = $jd[$appid]['data'];

$gprice = $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
$price = number_format($gprice / 100, 2);

echo 'Price: $' .$price;

?>
```

This is the way I tried to combine it but it hangs or errors.

```
<?php

$glist = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/aksn1p3r/games?tab=all&xml=1';
$gxml = simplexml_load_file($glist);

foreach($gxml->games->game as $game) {

$appid = $game->appID;
$glink = $game->storeLink;
$gname = $game->name;
$glogo = $game->logo;

echo '<p>'. $appid . ': <a href="'. $glink .'">'. $gname .'<br>';
echo '<img src="'. $glogo .'" /></a><br>';

$gjson = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=' . $appid;
$fgc = file_get_contents($gjson);
$jd = json_decode($fgc, true);

$gdata = $jd[$appid]['data'];

$gprice = $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
$price = number_format($gprice / 100, 2);

echo 'Price: $' .$price. '</p>';    
}

?>
```

I was expecting it to use the **$appid** each loop, to construct the link to the source: **$gjson**,  and then **file_get_contents($gjson);** to fetch the data and then echo that **$gprice** before moving on to next item.

Any pointers or errors I made, please help me to make it work?

Comment: `it hangs or errors` - do you get any error messages? You might want to check that you have enough error reporting configured (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). In other, I usually find `print_r` pretty useful when debugging (http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set("display_errors",1); ... shows anything? also file_get_contents() errors?

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset type in /steamgame.php on line 27
In my code that line 27 is this one: 

`$jd = json_decode($fgc, true);

$gdata = $jd[$appid]['data'];`

Comment: You get the error becasue `$appid` is not a string. Cast it to string: `(string) $appid` (works with simplexmlelement which is what you use). It's a common mistake, easy to fix if you know how. Work actively with error reporting and error logging because PHP tells you where a (potential) issue can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is nothing wrong in your code itself... the only error is that `$appid` in that line should be `integer`, not `string`.

```
$gdata = $jd[$appid]['data'];
```

You think that script hangs - well, it doesn't. It is running fine and doing its work. 
The problem is the way you are retrieving data - It isn't so fast.

Your list contains over 100 games. So basically your script is opening **appdetails** remote file and `json_decode`s it over 100 times. It takes a while and there is no output until `foreach` loop stops executing, so you can think that script hangs.

I modified your code a bit so you can see what is it about.

```
<?php

$glist = 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/aksn1p3r/games?tab=all&xml=1';
$gxml = simplexml_load_file($glist);

$i = 0; //just used to exit loop after 5 executions
foreach($gxml->games->game as $game) {
    if($i >= 5) {
        break;
    }
    $appid = $game->appID;
    $glink = $game->storeLink;
    $gname = $game->name;
    $glogo = $game->logo;

    echo '<p>'. $appid . ': <a href="'. $glink .'">'. $gname .'<br>';
    echo '<img src="'. $glogo .'" /></a><br>';

    $gjson = 'http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=' . $appid;
    $fgc = file_get_contents($gjson);
    $jd = json_decode($fgc, true);

    $gdata = $jd[intval($appid)]['data']; //$appid needs to be integer here, not string

    $gprice = $gdata['price_overview']['final'];
    $price = number_format($gprice / 100, 2);

    echo 'Price: $' .$price. '</p>';    

    $i++;
}

?>
```

Run it and wait few seconds. It should display 5 games with their prices (or error if game is free to play...).

Now, if it takes about five seconds to load images and prices of five games, It will take about 2 minutes to process all 100+ games. You should do it other way if you don't want to wait so long.

Comment: Thanks a lot for assuring me that the logic of my code was all good and that the integer must be used, weird though that it must be integer and not simple string.

I'm also unsure what would be another way to get info faster, maybe to store it for the first time into a MySQL and then later its faster to access from MySQL?

Comment: That might be a good idea, but for first time it will still be time consuming operation.